# Running multiple sql files that have stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, database, python-2.7, odbc, pyodbc

I am trying to run multiple sql files from a directory. This is my code to do that.

```
import pyodbc
import glob2

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=C1-HP;DATABASE=Traf;UID=sa;PWD=c@2121')
cursor = cnxn.cursor()  
path = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Crash\\*.sql'   
files=glob2.glob(path)   
for name in files:     
    with open(name, 'r') as inserts:
        for statement in inserts:  
            cursor.execute(statement)
            cnxn.commit()
    name.close()
```

However, I keep getting this error:

> File "uploadPy.py", line 11, in 
>       cursor.execute(statement) pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][ SQL Server]Could not
>   find stored procedure 'GO'. (2812) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Any ideas on how to solve this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like one of the .sql file has `GO` in it. `GO` is a batch separator only understood by `SSMS` and is not a SQL keyword.

Comment: @Raj Sorry if this may seem like a dumb question. Kinda new to this. So you're saying using pyodbc would not work in this case pretty? Or can it work with SSMS as well?

Comment: I am about to try pymssql to see how well it works.

Comment: Please search your SQL files for the word `GO`. Remove if any and it should work fine

Comment: it is a lot of sql files. It will be too much work to do that.

Comment: You could do a recursive case insensitive search for 'go\n' and replace it with '' across the files. You can do this in most editors like Sublime.